# How do I get deb2pet for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

How do I get deb2pet for Ubuntu? You may be wondering why I want a program that converts Debian packages to puppy packages installed on a Debian-based system. Well, I use Ubuntu and I am one of the new AnitaOS contributors. I would like to have deb2pet installed on my Ubuntu system so I can port software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer. The creator of the Linux distro AnitaOS (Darren Hale), told me that "deb2pet" only exists as a *.pet package for Puppy Linux distros. No Debian packages exist for deb2pet.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you have came across to this?

There is mirrors for that package as I suppose.

http://www.filewatcher.com/m/deb2pet.rpm2pet-0.0.4.pet.968-0.html

Comment: Thanks, but I have a Ubuntu system. "*.pet" files do not install on Ubuntu, and alien cannot convert pet files to deb packages. I need to install deb2pet on Ubuntu (a Debian system). I can find deb2pet, but not for a Debian-based system.